# Underscore Remove the Value without replace original variable

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.string.js

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to find the value in the object and remove the value has been found in the exist object. For example,

Current JSON Object:

```
exist=[{"x":6811,"y":15551,"a":["aa","ab","ac"]},{"x":6811,"y":15552,"a":["bb"]},{"x":6812,"y":15551,"a":["aa","cc"]}]
```

I want to find the "a" Key with value aa

The last result is

```
exist= [{"x":6811,"y":15552,"a":["bb"]}]
found= [{"x":6811,"y":15551,"a":["aa","ab","ac"]},{"x":6812,"y":15551,"a":["aa","cc"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without underscore:

```js
let exist= [
    { x: 6811, y: 15551, a: ['aa', 'ab', 'ac'] },
    { x: 6811, y: 15552, a: ['aa', 'bb'] },
    { x: 6812, y: 15551, a: ['cc'] },
];

const found = exist.filter(({ a }) => a.includes('aa'));
exist = exist.filter(({ a }) => !a.includes('aa'));

console.log('found:', found);
console.log('exist:', exist);
```

Comment: let exist= [
    { x: 6811, y: 15551, a: ['aa', 'ab', 'ac'] },
    { x: 6811, y: 15552, a: ['aa','bb'] },
    { x: 6812, y: 15551, a: ['cc'] },
];

const index = exist.findIndex(({ a }) => a.includes('aa'));
if (index > -1) {
    const found = exist.splice(index, 1);

    console.log('found:', found);
    console.log('exist:', exist);
}

Comment: If there is two aa in different object, its unable to find it

Comment: Ok, do you need to mutate `exist` object or create a new one

Comment: if new one, then the solution is in the edited initial message

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*.reject*](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) with [.contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) and [_.result](http://underscorejs.org/#result) combination

```js
exist=[
{"x":6811,"y":15551,"a":["aa","ab","ac"]},{"x":6811,"y":15552,"a":["bb"]},{"x":6812,"y":15551,"a":["aa","cc"]}, {"x":6812,"y":15551}
]

exist = _.reject(exist, function(item){ 
    return _.contains(_.result(item, "a"), "aa"); 
})

console.log(exist);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```